# Tkinter's widget.configure inside a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to change text of Tkinter Label based on done calculations. I am using simple `label.configure(text="something new")`. The problem is that I need to do so in every iteration of while loop. The process just waits till the loop is done and then shows the last result. I need them continuously.

```
def new_frequency_1000times():
  k=1
  while k>1000:
   #steps to determine new frequency f
   freq_out.configure(text=str(f))
   k=k+1

master=Tk()
freq_out = Label(master)
freq_out.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_freq=Button(okno, command=new_frequency_1000times, text="Get new f")
button_freq.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Any idea how to force the "evaluation" inside a loop?

Comment: Why not just put the config inside your while loop? And code might show the problem better.

Comment: I actually did that. Right you are, code will be here in a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a `while` loop running in the main even thread. So, it's blocking until the while loop is completed. Use `after` or `threading`.

Here's a small example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def new_frequency_1000times(k=0):

    if k < 1000:
        freq_out.configure(text=str(k))
        #1000 ms = 1 seconds, adjust to taste.
        root.after(10, lambda: new_frequency_1000times(k+1))

root=tk.Tk()
freq_out = tk.Label(root)
freq_out.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_freq=tk.Button(root, command=new_frequency_1000times, text="Get new f")
button_freq.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the window system events to have anything visible occur. Doing anything in a tight loop like this is just going to lock up your UI. Instead you need to use the `after` method to schedule the change as some interval and allow the event loop to process the necessary UI events.