# How can i make this code do what it's supposed to do?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, colors, background

So, what I am trying to do is when you open the window, it starts a process in which every 0.2 seconds it changes the first and 3rd value of the color (in which it converts the elements of the range into a hex value and then a string) to go from rgb( 86, 32, 86) to rgb(126, 32, 126). Although I thought this might just work, it doesn't. I only get a background of the first color and that's all.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
for i in range(86,126):
    h = hex(i)
    h = str(h)
    h = h[2] + h[3]
    root.configure(background=("#" + h + "32" + h ))
    time.sleep(0.2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please put some more effort in giving your question a title that summarizes the question. With the title you have now, no one that has the same question and starts googling will ever find this question. There's some good info on the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page about titles.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `after` function to give the window system time to process updates. Calling window update functions in a loop like that on the main thread will lock up the window until the loop terminates.

Try moving the code in the for loop into a new function, say `updateBackground`, and making it call itself recursively using after:

```
def updateBackground(i):
    # ...
    if i < 126:
        root.after(200, lambda: updateBackground(i + 1))
```

Note that I used a lambda in order to increment i.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36670519/1757964

Comment: I don't really understand

Comment: You could eliminate lambda by doing `root.after(200, updateBackground, i+1)` -- any additional arguments to `after` are passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue with this code is the use of `sleep()`. Because Tkinter is a single thread application and is event driven what ends up happening when you use `sleep()` the entire Tkinter instance freezes.

To work around this Tkinter provides a method called `After()` that is designed to schedule an event to happen after a time. So to get the same affect you are trying to get with sleep we can instead create a function that can call itself after 0.2 sec and provide it with the starting number and ending number.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

def do_something(start_number, end_number):
    if start_number <= end_number:
        h = str(hex(start_number))[2:] # combined all your work on h to one line
        root.configure(background=("#{}32{}".format(h, h)))
        start_number += 1
        root.after(200, do_something, start_number, end_number)

do_something(86, 126)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that the color change is mild and hard to see. If you increase the `end_number thought it will become more obvious.